# How to make two images within same class of different size as desired?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a class `cbImage` and for all the images the CSS is fixed

```css
.cbImage img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

}
```

Now, my problem is that I dont want all images of same width and height.

How can I change the width and height of different images as desired ?

One image of one panel:

```html
<div class="cbImage w3">


  <div class="panel">

    <div class="form">


     <div class="login">Recent badges</div>



     <span class="fa-stack fa-5x has-badge" data-count="6">

      <div class="badgesize">

          <img src="images/7.png" width=100, height=100 alt="">



        </div>

   </span>

   </div>
```

The other image:

```html
  <div class="cbImage active signin agileits">

  <form >


   <figure class="snip1336">
    <img src="images\44.jpg" alt="sample87" />
    <figcaption>
      <img src="images\ownpic.jpg" alt="profile-sample4" class="profile" />
```

As you can see both the class has name `cbImage`.

So the size is getting fixed.

I want the images of both class to have different size.

Also many other CSS are there I cannot just change the name and set the width and height.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it this way.

```
    <img class="example_class">
    <img class="example_class" style="width:60px;height:60px;">
```

As you can see if you have style there it will listen to style not to class.

Answer (score 1):

try using this.

```
// parent div
<div>
  <img class="example_image" src="image_path">
  <img class="example_image" src="image_path" style="width:yourimagewidth; height:yourimageheight;">

</div>
```

you have to use **inline-css** to differentiate your one of the image. As first it will take your **inline-css** property's value and then it will go for external CSS